# How to watch a service with multiple processes with Monit?

Tags: monit, system-monitoring, sympa

I'm trying to watch the mailing list manager sympa with monit. A running sympa instance consists of multiple processes for the different tasks of list management (e.g. a separate process for archiving emails), but all processes are started/stopped with a single init script.

Optimally, monit should alert me if any of the services fails and then restart sympa, but restart it only once.
A first solution looked like this:

```
check process sympa
  with pidfile /var/run/sympa/sympa.pid
  start program = "/etc/init.d/sympa start"
  stop program = "/etc/init.d/sympa stop"
check process sympa_bounced
  with pidfile /var/run/sympa/bounced.pid
  start program = "/etc/init.d/sympa start"
  stop program = "/etc/init.d/sympa stop"
check process sympa_bulk
  with pidfile /var/run/sympa/bulk.pid
  start program = "/etc/init.d/sympa start"
  stop program = "/etc/init.d/sympa stop"
```

However, if I stop sympa manually, the init script will be executed multiple times, once for every service I define (because every service failed).

My second approach was to define dependencies and only alert if any of the  subservices fail:

```
check process sympa
  with pidfile /var/run/sympa/sympa.pid
  start program = "/etc/init.d/sympa start"
  stop program = "/etc/init.d/sympa stop"
  depends on sympa_bounced, sympa_bulk
check process sympa_bounced
  with pidfile /var/run/sympa/bounced.pid
  if does not exist then alert
check process sympa_bulk
  with pidfile /var/run/sympa/bulk.pid
  if does not exist then alert
```

But since the subservices are not restarted, the main service will also not be restarted. So I figured I could 'fake' a restart by setting start/stop to `/bin/true`:

```
check process sympa
  with pidfile /var/run/sympa/sympa.pid
  start program = "/etc/init.d/sympa start"
  stop program = "/etc/init.d/sympa stop"
  depends on sympa_bounced, sympa_bulk
check process sympa_bounced
  with pidfile /var/run/sympa/bounced.pid
  start program = "/bin/true"
  stop program = "/bin/true"
check process sympa_bulk
  with pidfile /var/run/sympa/bulk.pid
  start program = "/bin/true"
  stop program = "/bin/true"
```

This does not work either, because if sympa_bulk fails, the PID file will not created before the sympa service is restarted, and this does not happen before the sympa_bulk is running again.

Is there a way to monitor such a service, get alert messages for all subservices, but restart the service only once, even if all subservices fail at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two possible solutions I've found. Both are not optimal but work in my scenario:

1. For every subservice, only check if the PID file exists and assume the service is online if the file exists. As before, the main service `sympa` depends on the subservices:

   ```
   check process sympa
     with pidfile /var/run/sympa/sympa.pid
     start program = "/etc/init.d/sympa start"
     stop program = "/etc/init.d/sympa stop"
     depends on sympa_bounced, sympa_bulk

   check file sympa_bounced
     with path /var/run/sympa/bounced.pid
     if does not exist then restart

   check file sympa_bulk
     with path /var/run/sympa/bulk.pid
     if does not exist then restart
   ```

   `restart` does nothing for files, but because `sympa` depends on the subservices, it will be restarted.
2. With newer monit versions, you can also execute a command and pass arguments to the command:

   ```
   check process sympa
     with pidfile /var/run/sympa/sympa.pid
     start program = "/etc/init.d/sympa start"
     stop program = "/etc/init.d/sympa stop"
     depends on sympa_bounced, sympa_bulk

   check program sympa_bounced
     with path "/usr/bin/pgrep --pidfile /var/run/sympa/bounced.pid"
     if does not exist then restart

   check program sympa_bulk
     with path "/usr/bin/pgrep --pidfile /var/run/sympa/bulk.pid"
     if does not exist then restart
   ```

   Similar to `check file`, the `restart` action does not do anything for programs, but forces the service `sympa` to restart.

   With older monit versions (e.g. `5.4`, the current version in Debian Wheezy), you cannot pass arguments to a command, so you could write a simple (one-line) script for each service which executes `/usr/bin/pgrep` with the respective arguments.

With both solutions, `sympa` is restarted *once* if any of the subservices fail or if `sympa` is not running at all.

Comment: With `sympa`, this actually does not work, because the init script of `sympa` is somewhat broken (at least in Debian). If the main process sympa is killed but other processes (such as `sympa_bounced`) are still running, then `/etc/init.d/sympa start` does not start the main process. Therefore I would not recommend to use this with `sympa`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get around it using `depends`

So something like

```
check process sympa_bulk
  with pidfile /var/run/sympa/bulk.pid
  depends on sympa
  start program = "/bin/true"
  stop program = "/bin/true"
```

Comment: This does not restart `sympa` if `sympa_bulk` fails, only vice versa.